# Defining a general function f with slot-holder arguments #1, #2

Tags: function-construction, slot

I am trying to get a general function $f$ accept slot-holder arguments #1, #2, where the actual arguments are lists {a1, a2,...} and {b1, b2,....}. I thought that this would involve some combination of the functions "Map" and "Apply" -  I have experimented with each function individually (I don't know how to combine them) but so far I have not managed to get the desired results.

1. I work only with "Apply", and this has no problem when the passed-in arguments are just single variables (not lists):

   Apply[f[#1, #2] &, {0, 1}]

The outcome is: f[0, 1]

When I try to pass in lists, for example #1 should accept {0,2} and #2 should accept {1,2} to produce a list {f[0,1], f[2,2]}, the output is instead:

```
f[{0, 2}, {1, 2}]
```

The code I used is:

```
   Apply[f[#1, #2] &, {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

However, I noticed that if the function is explicitly defined, for example take a simple function like f[#1, #2]=#1+#2, then the output is correct.

```
Apply[#1 + #2 &, {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}]
```

which produces:

```
{1, 4}
```

2. I also try to use "Map" (or /@), but it only works with a single slot-holder argument. For example

   f[#] & /@ {a, b, c, d, e}

gives:

```
{f[a], f[b], f[c], f[d], f[e]}
```

but if I put:

```
f[#1, #2] & /@ {{a, b, c, d, e}, {m, n, p, q, r}}
```

the result is:

```
{f[{a, b, c, d, e}, #2], f[{m, n, p, q, r}, #2]}
```

and not the desired result, which should be:

```
{f[a,m], f[b,n], f[c,p], f[d,q], f[e,r]}
```

I would be grateful if anyone could help me with this.

Comment: If you try `f @@@ {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}` you will get `{f[0,2], f[1,2]}`.  Or, `Map[Apply[f], {{0, 2}, {1, 2}}]`

Comment: I recommend reading the documentation for the functions `MapThread` and `Thread` and also for the `Listable` attribute. That should give you a better understanding of how to manipulate lists with functions.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out MapThread (also pointed out later by Daniel). Indeed that works.

Comment: `f @@@ Transpose@{{a, b, c, d, e}, {m, n, p, q, r}}`, too.

Answer (score 1):

Apply[f,arg] (or f /@ arg)is the same as f[arg]. If the function needs 2 arguments, you need to deliver 2 arguments. E.g.

```
(#1 + #2) &[{1, 2}, {3, 4}]
(* {4, 6} *)
```

Equally, the larger form needs a list of 2 arguments:

```
Apply[(#1 + #2) &, {{1, 2}, {3, 4}}]
(* {4, 6} *)
```

Map , on the other hand, applies the function to every element of the argument t. By default to the first level of the argument. E.g.:

```
Map[(# + 1) &, {1, 2}]
(* {2, 3} *)
```

or

```
(# + 1) & /@ {1, 2}
(* {2, 3} *)
```

Comment: Thanks for taking time to post your answer. However, the problem with defining the general function f that can accept the slot-holder arguments (which are lists) remain. I understand that if I just specify the explicit form of f, there is no problem in passing in lists to #1, #2. The problem lies in keeping f general.

Comment: Your example `f[#1, #2] & /@ {{a, b, c, d, e}, {m, n, p, q, r}}` is wrong syntax. This needs MpThread, e.g.: `MapThread[f[#1, #2] &, {{a, b, c, d, e}, {m, n, p, q, r}}]`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. MapThread is what I need for my code !